# Building websites for dummys

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I want to build a simple website with 4 pages and only language that i know is c#.

That's why i will use asp.net framework on visualstudio.

I Designed whole my webpages on photoshop however i can't use div tags, it seems complicated to me. I know, most of you know divs perfectly however i can not.

Is there any software or some simple sites that generates div templates?

I searched a lot however i couldn't find any simple site or program for that.

What are your suggestions, how should i move forward?

Comment: Here you go:
<div>This is a div</div>

Comment: [Learn web development | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn)

Answer (score 3):

If you using Visual Studio, one can use a programm called Wisej in conjunction with Visual Studio to build a custom website without dirrectly using html, css, or etc. It has a free trial version which is farly good.Check out for example the site www.hrtms.com was devloped using this technology.

Comment: wow, this seems cool. i will try.

Comment: Wisej is intended to build web sites but rather web applications, LOB web applications.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's that hard to be honest... I've always found watching a video on PluralSight is usually an excellent starting point for something I don't understand... They do a free trial too. There are plenty of videos on Web development give it a go!